# jQuery DataTable + JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON code:

```
"rows": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "nazwa1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "nazwa2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "nazwa3"
        },
        ...
        {
            "id": 99,
            "name": "nazwa99"
        }
    ]
```

In jQuery I have a JSON object in `listName`

the script is as follows:

```
$('#displayData').dataTable({
    "aaData": listName,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "id" },
        { "mDataProp": "name" }
    ]
});
```

But is wrong, how can I complete data in jQuery from listName?

Comment: What do you mean by _In jQuery I have JSON object in listName_?

Comment: I want pass data from listName to dataTable (the lat script in my post) and show on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fxnRelatedData = function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#displayData').change(function () {
                $.each(rows, function (index) {
                       /* give some class name to your table rows*/
                        $(".ClassName").html(rows[index].name);
                 });      
            });
        });
    };
```

fxnRelatedData();

Comment: Yes I want display json values in a table, but I don't understand what do you mean 'ques r8'?